# SQL counting multi lines with each other using group by

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I'm using the following query to get an overview of my results. At this moment the query shows 4 different rows instead of 2. I want to the first 3 columns as key for my query. Suggestions to do this?

```
select 
    r.ID, m.MATERIALID, m.LOT, ms.AMMOUNT as aantal, 
    m.NETPRICE as prijs, 
    (ms.AMMOUNT * m.NETPRICE) as Total 
from 
    rc_recall r 
inner join 
    RC_RECALLMATSTORE ms on r.ID = ms.RECALLID 
inner join 
    RC_RECALLMATERIAL m ON ms.RECALLID = m.RECALLID and ms.LINE = m.LINE 
where 
    r.ID = '2015073' and d.LANG = 'FR'
group by 
    r.ID, m.MATERIALID m.LOT, ms.AMMOUNT, m.NETPRICE;
```

The result I get:

```
2015073 | 100654643 | 1 | 2 | 0.9200    | 1.8400000
2015073 | 100654643 | 1 | 5 | 0.9200    | 4.6000000
2015073 | 100654643 | 2 | 3 | 0.9200    | 2.7600000
2015073 | 100654643 | 2 | 5 | 0.9200    | 4.6000000
```

Is it possible to count the rows with the same: 'r.ID, m.MATERIALID, m.LOT' with each other?

Result I want:

```
2015073 | 100654643 | 1 | 7 | 0.9200    | 6.4400000
2015073 | 100654643 | 2 | 8 | 0.9200    | 7.3600000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `sum()` and other aggregation functions:

```
select r.ID, m.MATERIALID, m.LOT, sum(ms.AMMOUNT) as aantal,
       sum(m.NETPRICE )as prijs, sum(ms.AMMOUNT * m.NETPRICE) as Total
from rc_recall r inner join
     RC_RECALLMATSTORE ms
     on r.ID = ms.RECALLID inner join
     RC_RECALLMATERIAL m
     ON ms.RECALLID = m.RECALLID and ms.LINE = m.LINE 
where r.ID = '2015073' and d.LANG = 'FR'
group by r.ID, m.MATERIALID, m.LOT;
```

You also need to fix the `group by` to be at the right granularity.

Answer (score 2):

Remove "ms.AMMOUNT" from your GROUP BY and add some SUM() functions should do the work :

```
select r.ID, m.MATERIALID, m.LOT
        , SUM(ms.AMMOUNT) as aantal
        , m.NETPRICE as prijs
        , SUM(ms.AMMOUNT * m.NETPRICE) as Total
from rc_recall r 
inner join RC_RECALLMATSTORE ms on r.ID = ms.RECALLID 
inner join RC_RECALLMATERIAL m ON ms.RECALLID = m.RECALLID and ms.LINE = m.LINE 
where r.ID = '2015073' and d.LANG = 'FR'
group by r.ID, m.MATERIALID, m.LOT, m.NETPRICE;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to group by AMMOUNT and NETPRICE then you have to aggregate them in some other way, for example MIN or SUM. This will return the output you describe above but you will need to confirm whether it's actually correct;

```
select r.ID, m.MATERIALID, m.LOT, ms.AMMOUNT as aantal, min(m.NETPRICE) as prijs, sum(ms.AMMOUNT * m.NETPRICE) as Total 
from rc_recall r 
inner join RC_RECALLMATSTORE ms on r.ID = ms.RECALLID 
inner join RC_RECALLMATERIAL m ON ms.RECALLID = m.RECALLID and ms.LINE = m.LINE 
where r.ID = '2015073' and d.LANG = 'FR'
group by r.ID, m.MATERIALID m.LOT;
```